# Drag and drop that doesn't delete the source node

Tags: treeview, kendo-ui

I got two kendoUI treeviews with drag and drop features. I want drop nodes from the second treeview to the first one but in the samples the event of drop deletes the node in the source treeview. Is it possible to move (clone) a node from one treeview to another one without deleting the source node?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

No but you can bind the change event, when you drag node you copy that node and re-add it to the treeview.